# How to select the last cell in a CollectionView?

Tags: ios, arrays, uicollectionview

I have an array that contains different images in which i am adding to the CollectionView with the "cellForItemAtIndexPath" method, and I am trying to use the "didSelectItemAtIndexPath" method to determine if the selected cell is the last one, but I can seem to get it right. Any help would be appreciated! Here is my method:

```
-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath  {

UICollectionViewCell *cell =[collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
  if(cell == [PicArray lastObject])
  {
    NSLog(@"selected last cell");
  }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath  {
    if ([indexPath.item == PicsArray.count-1]) {
       NSLog(@"selected last cell");
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

What i am using is UICollectionView inbuild method

```
override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, willDisplayCell cell: UICollectionViewCell, forItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        if indexPath.row == dataSource.count - 1 {
            // Last cell is visible
            if self.pagination.has_more {
                fetchFeeds()
            }
        }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. (count is a count of the objects in the array).

```
-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath  {

NSIndexPath *indexPath2 = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:(int)count inSection:0];

if([indexPath isEqual:indexPath2])
    {
    UICollectionViewCell *cell =[collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
     NSLog(@"selected last cell");
    }
}
```